# How to add new posts on my blog using html?

Tags: html, css

I've create one blog using html5 and css3. I need to add new posts on that blog by clicking a button. If I'll click that button one text area has to be open and it'll have the options like adding image, video and text. For example the text area that will be used to create questions in stack overflow site. Please help me to make this one...

Regards,

Sandra

Comment: Maybe you should post some parts of the code you have. I somehow understood what you want to have, and I can only give you some hints. I won't wrote code for you! I also think that the answer from ahmad is useful and you will learn something if you try it...

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. In its current form your question is not answerable in a meaningful way, because it is too broad. Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27686894/edit) your post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to use a rich text editor wrote in Javascript ( you can find some on Internet) and also, you have to write some PHP to send the the input from textarea( when click on submit or publish button) to a table in database.

Examples of rich text editors:
http://www.tinymce.com/ and
http://nicedit.com/

About the php part, you can find some examples on http://www.w3schools.com/php/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of server side language. You can use PHP/ even add your theme in wordpress so that you can add required functionality